# Doesn't save form in django python foreignkey

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

There is a form with `input text`, which is not saved and throws a `ValidationError`, because there is no such value in the `foreignkey` model.

The problem is that the check goes against `pk`, but the `name`. How to do it? (via `select` it is impossible, since this is entered and `ajax` gives him options).

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey('Service', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms**

```
 class SimpleOrderAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Orders
            fields = ['service']       
            widgets = {
            'service': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'ajax-service', 'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}),
        } 
    
        def clean_service(self):
            name = self.cleaned_data['service']        
            try:
                get_service = Service.objects.get(name=name)
                return get_service.pk
            except get_service.DoesNotExist:
                return name
```

**picture html form:**

[image]

**UPD**:
a question in a different vein: how to change validation from pk to name field in input forms?

**UPD2**:
when entering the correct value into input, it outputs: Choose the correct option. Your option is not among the valid values. the error is that when entering, you must specify the pk field for the Service model and then the model is saved. And how to make the comparison by the name field take into account when writing the form?

**UPD3**: already asked this question in a different vein here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351582/choose-the-correct-option-validationerror-django-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67348807/choose-the-correct-option-your-option-is-not-among-the-valid-values-django-pyt)

**UPD4:** update widget in forms

**UPD5:**

```
def ajax_request(request):
    model = request.GET.get('model')
    if model:
        if model == 'service':
            service = request.GET.get('one_form-service', None)
            qry = Service.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=service)).values_list('name', flat=True)
            qry = list(qry)
            if not qry or service == '':
                response = {
                    'is_taken': '',
                    'is_exist': False,
                }
            else:
                response = {
                    'is_taken': qry,
                    'is_exist' : True,
                }
            return JsonResponse(response)
```

Comment: How is that field not rendered as a select tag? Are you rendering the form _manually_?

Comment: Plus since you say you are getting the choices via ajax, why don't you simply set the value to the pk using javascript in that case (The input tag the user fills can simply be one for taking input and not the one posted)? Plus there are already some javascript libraries out there for such things See https://select2.org/ this even has a python package to use with django (https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat, sry, upd widgets in forms

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat, values can be 1000, so the select is not available. 10 values are offered through ajax and are substituted by pressing

Comment: See my second comment select2 can get data from ajax, plus it also has other features like paginating / infinite scroll on those select tags

Comment: @JopaBoga, what do you use for frontend? What does `ajax-service` do?

Comment: @NKSM, update 5. returns the name foreignkey field

Comment: @JopaBoga, if you are using jQuery, look at https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JopaBoga, or add the second input field to show the name of Service and the first input as `HiddenInput` for setting the value of service.